# Convert ByteMessage to String?

Tags: java, jms

What is best way to convert `ByteMessage` to `String`? I have the following code, do we have a more clean way?

```
BytesMessage byteMessage; // set byteMessage

byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int)byteMessage.getBodyLength()];

for (int i = 0; i < (int) byteMessage.getBodyLength(); i++) {
    byteArr[i] = byteMessage.readByte();
}
String msg = new String(byteArr);
```

Comment: The obvious way is `byteMessage.toString()`, or you want other format?

Comment: I only need the body message, not the header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first it would probably be more efficient to call readBytes(byte[]).

second, you are converting the bytes to a String using the platform character encoding, which is always dangerous.  you should be using an explicit charset.  either one known to be specified for the message type, or possibly a charset included as a message property.

Answer (score 3):

The [BytesMessage specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html) has a method readUTF() that might be helpful. Just replace all lines from BytesMessage up to the definition of the String with a call to this method.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out

```
 String msg = byteArr.readUTF();
```

You can also avoid the loop by using

```
 byteMessage.readBytes(byteArr);
```

Comment: Why not? I'll check the javadoc again

Comment: you're right, i quickly skimmed the javadoc and didn't see it was talking about 2 separate cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that these bytes are UTF-8 encoded, use [`BytesMessage.readUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html#readUTF%28%29) convenience method:

```
String s = byteMessage.readUTF();
```

If the `byte[]` array represents a string encoded with a different character encoding, e.g. UTF-16, use [`String(byte[], java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor:

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int)byteMessage.getBodyLength()];
byteMessage.readBytes(byteArr); 
String msg = new String(byteArr, "UTF-16");
```

Finally, consider using [`TextMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/TextMessage.html) to avoid the whole hustle.